# Rails console error stacktrace is extremely large

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm trying to figure out why the console is outputting objects in a stacktrace as if they were inspected.

I'm using the api version of rails 6. So far I've tried lowering the log level, setting `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` and attempted using minitest-reporters but nothing has worked.

Here's an example result from running `rails t`

```
rails test test/controllers/players_controller_test.rb:21

E

Error:
PlayersControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NoMethodError: undefined method `players' for #<PlayersControllerTest:0x000055e0a12f1728 @_routes=nil, @NAME="test_should_get_index", @failures=[#<Minitest::UnexpectedError: Unexpected exception>], @assertions=0, @integration_session=#<#<Class:0x000055e0a0cf5018>:0x000055e0a12eb490 @_routes=nil, @app=#<Api::Application:0x000055e09d3e4440 @_all_autoload_paths=["/home/code/splendor/api/app/channels", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/controllers", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/controllers/concerns", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/jobs", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/mailers", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/models", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/models/concerns"], @_all_load_paths=["/home/code/splendor/api/lib", "/home/code/splendor/api/vendor", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/channels", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/controllers", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/controllers/concerns", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/jobs", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/mailers", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/models", "/home/code/splendor/api/app/models/concerns"], @app=#<Rack::Cors:0x000055e09cca0850 @app=#<ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization:0x000055e09cca2678 @app=#<Rack::Sendfile:0x000055e09cca2ce0 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Static:0x000055e09cfeb208 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Executor:0x000055e09cfeb5a0 @app=#<RailsPerformance::Rails::MiddlewareTraceStorerAndCleanup:0x000055e09cfeb6e0 @app=#<RailsPerformance::Rails::Middleware:0x000055e09cfeb7d0 @app=#<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x000055e09e1e5d78 @name="ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache", @local_cache_key=:active_support_cache_null_store_local_cache_6500, @app=#<Rack::Runtime:0x000055e09cfebb68 @app=#<ActionDispatch::RequestId:0x000055e09cfebca8 @app=#<ActionDispatch::RemoteIp:0x000055e09cfebde8 @app=#<Rails::Rack::Logger:0x000055e09cfebed8 @app=#<ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions:0x000055e09cfebfa0 @app=#<ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions:0x000055e09d3d4360 @app=#<ActionDispatch::ActionableExceptions:0x000055e09d3d4680 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Reloader:0x000055e09d3d4860 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Callbacks:0x000055e09d3d49c8 @app=#<Rack::Head:0x000055e09d3d4bd0 @app=#<Rack::ConditionalGet:0x000055e09d3d4d10 @app=#<Rack::ETag:0x000055e09d3d4ef0 @app=#<Warden::Manager:0x000055e09d3d5490 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:jwt, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>#<Devise::Delegator:0x000055e09c52b908>}, @app=#<Warden::JWTAuth::Middleware:0x000055e09d3d55d0 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x000055e09e6713b0>>>, @cache_control="max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", @no_cache_control="no-cache">>>>, @executor=#<Class:0x000055e09c99af20>>>, @routes_app=#<Api::Application:0x000055e09d3e4440 ...>, @response_format=:api, @interceptors=[]>, @exceptions_app=#<ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions:0x000055e09c8960e8 @public_path=#<Pathname:/home/code/splendor/api/public>>>, @taggers=[]>, @check_ip=true, @proxies=[#<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0>, #<IPAddr: IPv6:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>, #<IPAddr: IPv6:fc00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/fe00:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0>, #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0>]>, @header="X-Request-Id">, @header_name="X-Runtime">>>>, @executor=#<Class:0x000055e09ccd9790>>, @file_handler=#<ActionDispatch::FileHandler:0x000055e09cfeaf38 @root="/home/code/splendor/api/public", @index="index", @precompressed=["br", "gzip", "identity"], @compressible_content_types=/\A(?:text\/|application\/javascript)/, @file_server=#<Rack::Files:0x000055e09cca3de8 @root="/home/code/splendor/api/public", @headers={"Cache-Control"=>"public, max-age=3600"}, @default_mime="text/plain", @head=#<Rack::Head:0x000055e09cca32d0 @app=#<Proc:0x000055e09cca3438 /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/files.rb:33 (lambda)>>>>>, @variation=nil, @mappings=[]>, @permissions=#<ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization::Permissions:0x000055e09cca2178 @hosts=[]>, @exclude=nil, @response_app=#<Proc:0x000055e09c1912e8 /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:61 (lambda)>>, @debug_mode=false, @logger_proc=nil, @logger=nil, @all_resources=[#<Rack::Cors::Resources:0x000055e09cc91580 @origins=["*"], @resources=[#<Rack::Cors::Resource:0x000055e09cc6af70 @path="*", @credentials=false, @max_age=7200, @pattern=/^(.*?)$/, @if_proc=nil, @vary_headers=nil, @public_resource=true, @headers=["authorization"], @methods=["get", "post", "put", "patch", "delete", "options", "head"], @expose=nil>], @public_resources=true>]>, @config=#<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000055e09dff8448 @root=#<Pathname:/home/code/splendor/api>, @generators=#<Rails::Configuration::Generators:0x000055e09c89f760 @aliases={}, @options={:rails=>{:orm=>:active_record, :test_framework=>:test_unit, :integration_tool=>:test_unit, :system_tests=>:test_unit}, :active_record=>{:migration=>true, :timestamps=>true}, :test_unit=>{:fixture=>false, :fixture_replacement=>:factory_bot}}, @fallbacks={}, @templates=[], @colorize_logging=true, @api_only=true, @hidden_namespaces=[], @after_generate_callbacks=[]>, @middleware=#<ActionDispatch::MiddlewareStack:0x000055e09c21bdd0 @middlewares=[Rack::Cors, ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization, Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Static, ActionDispatch::Executor, RailsPerformance::Rails::MiddlewareTraceStorerAndCleanup, RailsPerformance::Rails::Middleware, ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware, Rack::Runtime, ActionDispatch::RequestId, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::ActionableExceptions, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, Warden::Manager, Warden::JWTAuth::Middleware]>, @javascript_path="javascript", @encoding=#<Encoding:UTF-8>, @allow_concurrency=nil, @consider_all_requests_local=false, @filter_parameters=[:passw, :secret, :token, :_key, :crypt, :salt, :certificate, :otp, :ssn], @filter_redirect=[], @helpers_paths=["/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/devise-4.8.1/app/helpers"], @hosts=[], @host_authorization={}, @public_file_server=#<ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions {:enabled=>true, :index_name=>"index", :headers=>{"Cache-Control"=>"public, max-age=3600"}}>, @force_ssl=false, @ssl_options={:hsts=>{:subdomains=>true}}, @session_store=:cookie_store, @time_zone="UTC", @beginning_of_week=:monday, @log_level=:debug, @cache_store=:null_store, @railties_order=[:all], @relative_url_root=nil, @reload_classes_only_on_change=true, @file_watcher=ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker, @exceptions_app=nil, @autoflush_log=true, @log_formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x000055e09e0076a0 @datetime_format=nil>, @eager_load=false, @secret_key_base=nil, @api_only=true, @debug_exception_response_format=:api, @x=#<Rails::Application::Configuration::Custom:0x000055e09e007600 @configurations={}>, @enable_dependency_loading=false, @read_encrypted_secrets=false, @content_security_policy=nil, @content_security_policy_report_only=false, @content_security_policy_nonce_generator=nil, @content_security_policy_nonce_directives=nil, @require_master_key=false, @loaded_config_version=6.1, @credentials=#<ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions {:content_path=>#<Pathname:/home/code/splendor/api/config/credentials.yml.enc>, :key_path=>#<Pathname:/home/code/splendor/api/config/master.key>}>, @autoloader=:zeitwerk, @disable_sandbox=false, @add_autoload_paths_to_load_path=true, @permissions_policy=nil, @rake_eager_load=false, @paths=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x000055e09e107e38 @path=#<Pathname:/home/code/splendor/api>, @root={"app"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x000055e09e107d48 @paths=["app"], @current="app", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x000055e09e107e38 ...>, @glob="{*,*/concerns}", @exclude=["assets", "javascript"], @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=true, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/assets"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x000055e09e107cd0 @paths=["app/assets"], @current="app/assets", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x000055e09e107e38 ...>, @glob="*", @exclude=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/controllers"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x000055e09e107c58 @paths=["app/controllers"], @current="app/controllers", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x000055e09e107e38 ...>, @glob=nil, @exclude=nil, @autoload_once=false, 
...
Finished in 5.930508s, 9.1055 runs/s, 13.1523 assertions/s.
54 runs, 78 assertions, 1 failures, 10 errors, 0 skips
```

[And a link to the full stacktrace as it was too large to fit](https://gist.github.com/bcowell/66ed496906d07ec280c75433f786d921)

Comment: There might be plenty of reasons: it might be done intentionally (by adding some custom error message formatter), or just accidentally - by overriding `to_s` method for some class that sits high in the ancestors chain (so this override affects more than it was planned) etc... Quite hard to say without debugging.

Comment: Did you find out the root cause? This has been trolling me too.

Comment: No I haven't found the root cause, but I did find a workaround which I posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround!

You create a custom initializer file in the `config/initializers` directory of your application that removes the variables that contain useless info. Once I removed the following the error messages were more useful.

Here's my `config/initializers/hide_test_error_trace.rb`:

```
ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.class_eval do
  def hide_test_error_trace
    @integration_session = nil
    @connection_subscriber = nil
    @tagged_logger = nil
    @delegate = nil
  end
end
```